# Can't submit Facebook Ad with api, new error code Your ad is ineligible for News Feed targeting

Tags: facebook, api, curl, parameters, ads

I was having trouble submitting an ad through the Facebook ads api, like I was doing before.

It seems a new problem has come up.  The Api of course only gives me a generic error "Invalid Parameter"  however in the past I noted this this comes up for basically any reason that ad creation fails and does not tell you anything specific.  In a different situation I used curl to the Facebook graph because I noted that it will give you additional information.  However not much more in this case.  Note the error message below the code.

```
    curl -X POST -F "name=Ad Administrator_15" 
-F "campaign_id=xxxxxxxxxx995" -F "creative={'creative_id': xxxxxxxxxx795}" / 
-F "adgroup_status=PAUSED" /
-F  "access_token={access_token}" / "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_{account_id}/adgroups"
```

This is the error received

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":1487757,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Ad Ineligible for Feed Targeting","error_user_msg":"Your ad is ineligible for News Feed targeting."}}
```

In checking on the facebook ads error message page.  The error is not even
listed, though many others are.

previously I was getting the invalid parameter message back from the API just because I had not put a payment profile on my ad account. But used curl instead to find out this message.  But after that I was creating ads just fine.  Seems like this is a new problem.

If I could ask Facebook directly.  I would ask "Hey can you put some descriptive error messages on your failures so that developers can see how to fix problems?"  I guess that's too much to ask.

Anyhow, I may note here that The Campain was newly created with the api, then the adset, then the ad creative with the ad image, all created fine with recorded IDs (I masked these ids mostly in the code shown here for security reasons).  When using these id's even outside of the API with curl I get the failure noted.  Here is what shows in the API for an error with the trace.

```
Invalid parameter 

/var/www/turnkey/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Client.php(191): FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException::create(Array, 500)
#1 /var/www/turnkey/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Request.php(276): FacebookAds\Http\Client->sendRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/turnkey/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(140): FacebookAds\Http\Request->execute()
#3 /var/www/turnkey/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(182): FacebookAds\Api->executeRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/turnkey/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Object/AbstractCrudObject.php(248): FacebookAds\Api->call('/act_xxxxxxxx40...', 'POST', Array)
#5 /var/www/turnkey/application/modules/Ads/models/FacebookAdsApi.php(473): FacebookAds\Object\AbstractCrudObject->create()
```

Here is a thought, if anyone, including someone at Facebook since they own this site, could tell me what is going on, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook documented required length for the message body for an ad Creative is that it needs to be a minimum length of 1 character and a maximum length of 90 characters. Before what would happen is that ads could be created.  Even with test content in the title and body of your ad.  Then they would not be approved if Facebook did not like the content.  Such as messages like "test title, test body" and things like this.  Facebook seems to be evaluating the text on submission now, rather than on ad approval.  I guess they want to cut down on unnecessary ad approvals. So with out updating their documentation.  It seems there are new requirements for the body field. And perhaps the title field.

All I did was lengthen the body of the ad message from 17 characters to 38 characters.  This did one of two things.  It made the field long enough to pass a new undocumented restriction, or, by adding some more words to the text they decided that it wasn't test message.

Here is the problem with that thinking on their part though.

## 1  I am paying for the ad, I should be able to put the content I want in it. As long as it is meaningful and doesn't violate some obvious certain policies for content such as obscenity etc.

## 2  If it's about the length rather than the content.  My ad that I am paying for that only has 17 characters, should be required to be longer if I just want to say something short.